# Converter for IEnumerable of Enums

Tags: c#, enums

My combo box is binding to a collection of Enums. I'm trying to filter out some of the enums from displaying.

I tried the following below, but it doesn't filter out anything, it simply returns the original collection.

```
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="Occurences" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ScheduleItems}, 
                                Converter={StaticResource ScheduleItemsEnumConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />

public class ScheduleItemsEnumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var collection = ((IEnumerable<LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems>)value).Cast<LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems>();
        collection  =
            collection.Where(
                x =>
                    !x.Equals(LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems.CapitalizedFee) ||
                    !x.Equals(LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems.CapitalizedInsurance) ||
                    !x.Equals(LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems.CapitalizedInterest));
        return collection;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I know the where clause is okay because the other method of populating a combo box worked fine.

```
public IEnumerable<LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems> EventTypes
{
    get
    {
        return
            Enum.GetValues(typeof(LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems))
                .Cast<LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems>()
                .Where(
                    x =>
                        !x.Equals(LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems.CapitalizedFee) ||
                        !x.Equals(LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems.CapitalizedInsurance) ||
                        !x.Equals(LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems.CapitalizedInterest));
    }
}
```

May I ask how am I suppose to apply a converter to a status resource or convert a enum collection

Comment: You should be using `&&` not `||`.

Comment: @juharr Thanks Homie!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is wrong.  You want to "and" the conditions not "or" them.  You also don't need the `Cast<LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems>`

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return  ((IEnumerable<LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems>)value)
        .Where(
            x =>
                !x.Equals(LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems.CapitalizedFee) &&
                !x.Equals(LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems.CapitalizedInsurance) &&
                !x.Equals(LoanCalculator.ScheduleItems.CapitalizedInterest));
}
```